# Meaning of "chiqueada"

Tags: méxico, idiomático

I am trying to understand the meaning of chiqueada, as told to me by my girlfriend in a loving manner. She used it as, "me siento como una niña chiqueada". I know it implies something like a young girl? Or maybe baby girl? Or maybe like a pampered girl?

If it helps, she's from Mexico, so I'm looking specifically more for definitions from that part of the world.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a word just from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"chiqueada" for she or "chiqueado" for him, means when a child receives a lot of attention: like gifts, food, candies, surprises, love etc. In your context this is good and we Mexican girls like to be "chiqueadas".

Comment: Yes, we had a great weekend together and she said it in a very positive way, so I think your answer is along the right lines. Thanks!

Comment: Heads up @JimBeam: Don't forget to pick your best answer (or the answer you like most), that way people gets rewarded (privilege).

Comment: Your welcome, that good that my answer has been helpful :)

Answer (score 7):

> chiqueado, chiqueada. adj. (De un niño) 1. Mimado. || 2. Malcriado.

Fuente: [Diccionario breve de mexicanismos, Guido Gómez de Silva](https://tajit.memberclicks.net/assets/documents/diccionario%20breve%20de%20mexicanismos%20segun%20guido%20gomez%20de%20silva.pdf), p. 55.

Comment: Interesting that, if I understand this definition correctly, it is ambiguous in the same way as the English word spoiled. The OP spoiled his girl friend by being really nice to her and pampering her, you spoil a child by giving in to its wishes all the time.

Comment: It's not vain to note that in many places in SouthAmerica, "niño" or "niña" are called "chico"/"chica". Then "chiqueada" means the subject of gifts or the center of the attention (things that in a sense you give to kids most of the time). My two cents...

Answer (score 4):

Chiqueado, chiqueada in México means 'spoiled' in English.

Answer (score 1):

### Giddy

> : playful and silly
>
> : feeling or showing great happiness and joy

Reading the word, "chiqueada" in context, it seems to me that "giddy" is the closest translation I can come up with.

> When I began to flirt with her she began to act like a giddy school girl.

I find that this is a close translation because it seems to match the gender of your "chiqueada".  I have only ever heard the word "giddy" used with women.  A giddy school boy would have a different name, and it probably would be against the rules to post it or describe it.

When I hear the word "giddy" I think of playful laughing by from a group of girls; gossiping and giggling, usually over boys they are interested in.

And, if the word "giddy" doesn't quite express what you're asking, then perhaps:

### Giggly

would suffice?

Comment: In the dialect spoken in south eastern England I would consider it an insult to call a woman giddy (unless she was suffering from vertigo of course).

Comment: Wow!  That's a whole new twist on the word.  This is the American usage.

Answer (score 0):

I’m from the central part of Mexico and when someone says that he or she is Chiqueado/chiqueada they are referring to the action of someone feeling spoiled or pampered by someone else wether it’s by parents, loved one or a significant other